# Хранение некоторых данных приложения в тегах meta, body?

Tags: php, html, auth

Хорошей ли практикой считается хранение некоторых данных (например, Facebook App ID, Google Client ID и т.д.) в теге meta:

```
    <head>
        <meta property="facebookAppID" content="123456789">
        <meta property="googleClientID" content="123456789">
    </head>
```

Или, например, теге body:

```
 <body data-facebook-app-id="123456789" data-google-client-id="123456789">
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все данные которые там будут станут публичными. Если вас устраивает - это и эти данные не нанесут вреда, то почему бы и нет.